# Start a process in minimized state with just one line. Is it possible

Tags: process, process.start, minimized

I have the code below to start a process in minimized state. It does work

```
Dim psi As New ProcessStartInfo("notepad")
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
Process.Start(psi)
```

However, I want to combine them into one line, it start the process but not in minimized state. how do I fix this? TIA

```
Process.Start("notepad").StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
 Process.Start(New ProcessStartInfo("notepad") With {.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized})
```